# Запуск приложения ASP.NET Core в IIS сразу при старте сайта

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

Вопрос: как запустить приложение ASP.NET Core сразу при старте сайта в IIS, а не при первом обращении к нему.

Есть следующая инфраструктура:

- Набор моих микрослужб, представляющих собой приложения на ASP.NET Core 3.1
- IIS 10
- Consul - это стороннее приложение, я использую его в качестве ServiceLocator'а.

В коде своих микрослужб я указал, чтобы они при старте регистрировались в Consul.
Клиентские приложения обращаются к Consul за сведениями, где запущена та или иная микрослужба. И если Consul обладает этой информацией, он её возвращает. Но для этого надо, чтобы микросервис стартанул и зарегистрировался в Consul.

Нажимаю "Запустить" у сайта в диспетчере служб IIS. "Нечто" запускается, но микросервис не стартует до момента первого обращения к нему. Пишу в строке браузера его адрес, и только в этот момент микросервис запускается и становится доступным в Consul. Меня это конечно же не устраивает: хост с сервером IIS может быть перезагружен без моего ведома, и все микросервисы окажутся недоступными.

Я нашёл информацию, что надо у пула приложений в IIS установить режим запуска `startMode=AlwaysRunning`. Сделал.
Потом у каждого сайта в IIS установил галку "Предварительная установка включена" (`preloadEnabled=true`). Сделал.

Эффекта в результате этих двух действий не добился.

Понимаю, что проблема вероятнее всего с IIS, где-то не включена какая-то галочка. Что мне ещё можно попробовать, куда копать?

P.S. являюсь околонулевым специалистом в IIS, поэтому в вышеприведённом тексте термины выбраны весьма неточные, но понятные. Прошу отнестись к ним снисходительно.
P.S.S. информация про Consul носит лишь информативный характер и к сути проблемы отношения не имеет.

Comment: Ну так уберите ненужную информацию из вопроса.

Comment: @4per, мне в том числе хотелось бы подискутировать и о Consul с теми, кому есть что сказать по теме. Возможно возникнут идеи, как можно решить проблему, зайдя с другой стороны.

Comment: Итого 8 упоминаний. Больше похоже на спам.

Comment: @IgorBorzenkov `как можно решить проблему, зайдя с другой стороны` Была похожая "проблема", пошерстив интернет ничего толкового не нашел. Поэтому решил довольно топорным способом: сделал сервис-пингалку сайта, который раз в определенное время стучится к сайту, тем самым не давая ему "уснуть".

Comment: @ГеннадийП, спасибо, сделал примерно также: создал в  **Планировщике заданий** Windows задание раз в день посылать запрос на сайт: `curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx`. Работает - факт, но на системах корпоративного уровня выглядит заплаткой. Со временем надеюсь разобраться, как сделать правильно.

Comment: @IgorBorzenkov Забыл добавить. Ну а в итоге у меня сейчас все сервисы висят за HAproxy, в котором настроен мониторинг бэкендов на IIS путем запроса проверочной страницы.